# Matrix vector form. Is this in the correct form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I have this question:

> Write the linear system
>   $$\begin{array}{rcr}-2x_1+x_2-4x_3 & = & 1 \\ x_1-2x_2 & = & -3 \\ x_1+x_2-4x_3 & = & 0 \end{array}$$
>   in the matrix-vector form $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$.

Is this what they want?

$$ 
x_1*
\begin{bmatrix}
  -2 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
+
x_2*
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\ -2 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
+
x_3*
\begin{bmatrix}
  -4 \\ 0 \\ -4
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\ -3 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: For general MathJax tips, you can take a look here : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference (See in particular the top-voted answer for matrices).

Comment: Is there anything I could improve which prevents you right now from accepting one of the given answers?

Answer (score 5):

I guess the matrix-vector form here refers to the matrix **A** and the vector **b**. I would suggest to rewrite the equation in the following way

$$\begin{pmatrix}-2&1&-4\\1&-2&0\\1&1&-4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}~=~\begin{pmatrix}1\\-3\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

To verify the L.H.S. you can just multiply the vector by the matrix and then your will get first guess.

Comment: What does pmatrix mean?

Comment: Why is the column of x's called a vector?

Comment: The *pmatrix*-command gives you the $()$ braces. For other kinds of matrices just search for the LaTeX commands. How would you call a single column instead?

Comment: You can interpret this system of equation as the point of intersection within $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the three given functions. For that every single variable represents on direction of the $3$-dimensional space you can just conclude setting the vector **x** as $\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}$ where $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the three directions towards the the $\mathbb{R}^3$-space.

Answer (score 1):

basically!

$
A = \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 & -4 \\ 1 & -2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & -4 \end{pmatrix}
$
and $b = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ yielding $Ax = b$.